# No match for 'operator=' in sort function

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, codeblocks

I'm trying to have a program write out all permutations of a string. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main () {
    string input;
    int length;
    cin >> input;
    input = sort(begin(input), end(input));
    length = input.length();
    do {
        cout << input;
        cout << "\n";
    } while (next_permutation(input,input+length));
}
```

However, I get the following error:

```
[path removed]\PermutIO.cpp|12|error: no match for 'operator=' in 'input = std::sort<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> > >(std::begin<std::basic_string<char> >((* & input)), std::end<std::basic_string<char> >((* & input)))'|
```

I am using Code::Blocks with g++ and have set it to use the C++11 standard. What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`sort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) method itself returns a `void`, so what you're trying to do is assigning `string` to `void`. 
Just write `sort(begin(input), end(input))` instead.

**Update:**
Well, let's analyze the error message that your compiler gives:

```
error: no match for 'operator=' in 'input = 
std::sort<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> > >
(std::begin<std::basic_string<char> >((* & input)), 
std::end<std::basic_string<char> >((* & input)))'
```

The last 3 lines might seem difficult and hard to understand, but the most important thing here is the first line:

```
no match for 'operator=' in 'input = ...
```

That means that the compiler **can't find a rule**, that can allow you to assign the `input` to something in the right side. So, now, when we've already know that the problem is in the assigning value, the debugging proccess is much simpler - we have to find what type of value does the `sort` method returns, we can do that simply by using google.

Comment: That was exactly the problem; I assumed it would return the sorted version of the object. Thanks! I will accept your answer once the time limit has expired.

Comment: @VirtualDXS Well, it's not necessary xD btw, I added a description of how you can read the error messages and find the problem by yourself :D

Comment: Ohhh, I see. I wasn't quite comprehending what it meant by "no match". Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This line is malformed because [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) returns `void`.

```
input = sort(begin(input), end(input));
```

You can not assign `void` to a `std::string`.

Remove `input =` from that line.  It's not needed.